# performance between DOM parsing and Regex

Tags: regex, http, dom

I'm doing something that dynamically loading content from a bunch of auto-fetch html sources, and I'm using Regex previously to get the data, but some friends of mine told me that it would be faster if using DOM, is that so and why?

Answer (score 3):

DOM is designed to parse HTML. Posting about parsing HTML using Regex will get a lot of people worked up on this site (just saw several posts on it yesterday).
Depending on what you're doing, on occasion, I will use Regex to get certain items from HTML or to see if the HTML has certain tags, but if you're trying to pull data or parse the HTML, you would be much better off using a good DOM parser.

You will have to be careful about what kind of DOM parser you use, for instance, the PHP DOM parser requires valid HTML (in my experience) so I had to use HTML tidy to clean it up before I got the expected results.
Here's a simple DOM parser that can handle invalid html: http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/index.htm
I'm using the one above to look through element attributes in html that I'm not 100% positive will always be valid.